# Global header/footer PHP?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a global header and footer for the whole site.

On the web, I found a way to do it in PHP.

- I changed the index.html to index.php
- I took the piece of header code and, with that, I created the header.php file
- Then, in index.php, I used  `<? php include 'includes / header.php'; ?>`

But the VS Code Live Server shows me the file's directory and not the `index.php`

This is my **header.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Marketing Hub</title>
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- menu -->
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MARKETING <span class="hub">HUB</span></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><img src="/immagini/menu.svg" width="30px" alt=""</span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="nav justify-content-end navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="servizi.html"> Servizi</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=“#”>Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=“#”>Contatti</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

And this is my **index.php**:

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>


    <!-- DIAMO FORMA ALLA COMUNICAZIONE -->
    <section id="intro">
        <div class="containerTitolo">
            <h1>Diamo forma alla <br> <span class="paroleVerdi">comunicazione</span></h1>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- chi  siamo -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg">
                <h2>Siamo <span class="paroleVerdi">HUB</span> di identità e di esperienze.</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg">
                <p>Per affiancare l’Azienda nelle esigenze strategiche, operative e di distribuzione dei prodotti,
                    abbiamo sviluppato un concentratore di expertise di differenti professionalità e di aziende che
                    operano come partner in MARKETING HUB.</p>

                <p>L’obiettivo è di fornire, attraverso un unico interlocutore, la soluzione a tutte le esigenze di
                    collocamento dell’output aziendale partendo dagli aspetti strategici e sviluppando una proposta
                    completa di strumenti operativi all’avanguardia.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should post info about your files directory. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Have you try for example to run indep.php inside localhost? maybe using xampp or similar?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm The Live Server shows me the listing Directory.
A list of all my files in my folder and nothing more...

Comment: @Sfili_81 I only use the Live Server of VS Code... it always worked...

Comment: Do you put file `header.php` in directory `includes` ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm yes. in my folder there are: index.php , style.css and
 a folder name "includes" where my header.php is.

Comment: Sounds like your system is not configured to look for an `index.php` file to serve instead of the directory listing, but only for `index.html` …? What happens when you explicitly request the `index.php`, instead of just the folder it is in?